# Load Data cannot be used in a Stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I am new to mysql. I have a requirement to load csv file into a table in my procedure.
I have tried using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE which does the job but when I use this code in my procedure, it says "Load Data" cannot be used in a Stored procedure".
Please help me in this..
Thanks!

Comment: You can't see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: I have tried a solution in which I concatenated the LOAD statement into a variable like:
SET @DynamicSQL=(CONCAT(" 
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/upload/11.24-12.02 trips.csv'
    INTO TABLE temp_csv_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS"));
Then I used this statement to execute the sql :

   PREPARE stmt FROM @DynamicSQL;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   COMMIT WORK;
But at the time of calling this procedure, I receive
Error Code: 1295
This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon for this. Is there any alternative for my requirement ?

Comment: Any reason why you want to do it in an SP?

Comment: I have to give this procedure to someone who will call it on a daily basis.

Comment: Is there any alternative or suggestion ?

Comment: Do you have access to some external scheduler like cron perhaps.

Comment: No. Actually, I heard it for the first time. I am new in mysql

Comment: Will this be a correct way to use a scheduler? As I want anyone at anytime may call it to load the csv into a table.

Comment: mysql event scheduler is a stored routine and cannot LOAD DATA

Comment: Then what should I do as an alternative ?

Comment: If the only resource you have is mysql then write the code, store it as a text file, copy and paste it when you want to run it.

Comment: I am currently doin it in the same way but the new requirement is to automate it. Like anyone just call the procedure(or any other thing) with the csv and it gets inserted into the table.